# Couchbase Server Crashes After Using Sometimes

Tags: couchbase

In my local machine (macOS Mojave, 8GB 2133MHz LPDDR3, 2.3GHz Intel Core i5) since I’ve installed and been using couchbase server 5.1.1, the cb server crashes after using it for sometimes. There is no specific amount of time. I assume when the cb gets some amount of hits. But I can assure I do not use it extensively (its local, right?). And when it does crash, my laptop produce huge amount of heat unless I quit the server and start again after it cools down.

Here is my server configuration - Data Service 2000 MB, Index Service 256 MB, Search Service 256 MB. I have only one bucket which I use.
Is it happening because of some misconfiguration? This crash thing also happened 2 times in my demo server too and I had to increase the server capability.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? You can find them here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-logs.html

Comment: Are you using FTS?

Comment: @JohanLarson just checked and found exit stat in indexer, projector areas. But can't understand what is written there... although they are 4days old. here it is  https://pastebin.com/Zeq4NPT0

Comment: @deniswsrosa not at all

Comment: @JohanLarson after collecting info using cbcollect_info and looking into the error.log, I find these 2 common message at the time when it did crashe - 'Failed to grab service index status', 'Failed to grab service fts status'. Here is details https://pastebin.com/cuhhRjjw. will you please check?